# Custom MFA ADFS extension does not work with e-mail claim

Tags: c#, adfs, multi-factor-authentication

I have built an MFA extension for ADFS using this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenfieldmsft/2014/03/24/build-your-own-external-authentication-provider-for-ad-fs-in-windows-server-2012-r2-walk-through-part-1/

I am trying get the incoming claim in the `IAuthenticationAdapter.BeginAuthentication(Claim claim, ...)` to have the e-mail of the user that is authenticating. Based on the guide, i should be able to specify in my metadata the `IdentityClaims` to return `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"` and then i should get the e-mail.

However, my code is never hit.

Instead, i get the following error in the Event Viewer logs:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: The identity information provided does not contain a Windows account name.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.External.ExternalAuthenticationHandler.ProcessContext(ProtocolContext context, IAuthenticationContext authContext, IAccountStoreUserData userData)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.External.ExternalAuthenticationHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.AuthenticationOptionsHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

I tried specifying the relying party trusts to pass on the LDAP parameters but i am unable to access those in my code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Background

We ran into this question when trying to debug this exact issue, ourselves. We were experimenting with `IAuthenticationAdapterMetadata.IdentityClaims`. When our adapter requested `emailaddress` as our input claim, ADFS threw the above exception immediately before calling `BeginAuthentication`.

The main issue was that our Claims Provider (Active Directory, in this case) was not configured to provide the user's email address. We discovered this with help from Microsoft's (free) [Claims X-Ray](https://adfshelp.microsoft.com/ClaimsXray/TokenRequest) service, which I highly recommend for those debugging ADFS claims issues.

Secondarily, ADFS was giving a misleading error. ADFS does not actually seem to validate the `Claim` value passed to `BeginAuthentication`. Once we resolved the main issue, there were no restrictions on the user's email address, so long as it was defined.

### Solution

**Note:** if you have multiple Claims Provider Trusts, you may need to do this with each of them.

1. Navigate to the `AD FS Management` app on the relevant machine.
2. Select `Claims Provider Trusts`.
3. Right click the provider you want to "fix" and select `Edit Claim rules...`
4. Select `Add Rule...` and then select `Send LDAP Attributes as Claims`.
5. I'm assuming you should select the provider you're working on as the `Attribute store` for this rule. You may need to experiment if you can't.
6. Map LDAP attribute `E-Mail-Addresses` to claim type `E-Mail Address`.
7. Save the new rule.

**Additional note:** Only the first value in the `E-Mail-Addresses` array will be sent to `BeginAuthentication`. This seems to be a quirk of the interface, not a quirk of this solution.